# TP-Link Archer MR200 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've just bought a TP-Link Archer MR200 router. It has two antennae, one in the left and another in the right.

If I remove the right-hand side antenna and leave the left one, the signal level doesn't change. If I remove the left one and leave the right one, there is no signal.

Is my router defective or is the left antenna the only one that is working?

If you have this router, can you please check it?